# Access data on sfr P1 using raw pointer

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, keil

**My Environment**

- IDE : Keil
- Processor : AT89C4051 (Simulation Mode)

I'm trying to work with *P1 register* (address 0x90 specified by datasheet) by setting its value to all 0 (RESET state) and setting some specific pin to be 1 (SET state). I try this code

```
int main() {
    *((unsigned char*)0x90) = 0;
    while(1) {
        *((unsigned char*)0x90) = 0xE0;
    }
}
```

**But nothing change.**

When I use this example every work flawlessly

```
sfr P1 = 0x90;
int main()
{
  P1 = 0;
  P1 = 0xE0;
  while(1);
}
```

My question is, what make the different between these code since it's all pointing at address 0x90 using *sfr* and *unsigned char* pointer.

Comment: One obvious bug is the lack of `volatile`. I just wrote a tutorial for how to write to microcontroller hardware registers [here](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276290). Also, you should disassemble the two examples and compare the machine code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access SFRs of the 8051 series microcontroller by indirect accesses.

On devices with more than 128 bytes internal RAM, the I/O addresses 0x80 to 0xFF are used for both the SFRs and the upper half of the internal RAM:

- SFRs are accessed by direct addressing only.
- The internal RAM is accessed by indirect addressing only.

**EDIT:**

Source: Right on the [product summary page](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/AT89C4051) there is the [8051 instruction set](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0509.pdf) that documents this on the very first page.

Comment: Please provide source of this info.I searched but i didn't got it.